# Examples of Google styled Maps? (including JSON)

Tags: google-maps

After watching a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ytLzKpngk) on creating different map styles with Google Maps, I have been having some fun playing around with the [Google Maps Style Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

I was hoping to find a gallery of user submitted Google Maps Styles, with accompanying JSON code so that I could pinch their hard work & cartography skills, and use on my own applications.

Has anyone come across either a collection of styles (+JSON) or at least some great examples of google maps styles, where the JSON is also available?

The closest I could find was [this](http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html).

Comment: If there are no existing galleries out there, happy to edit my Q and make it c-wiki, to make this Q/A itself a list of google styled maps from the GIS-SE community.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a site that might be exactly what you are looking for:

http://snazzymaps.com

It's a repository for Google Maps color schemes with JSON code and downloadable examples. There are only a few styles up now that I've created myself but I just whipped up the site over the last week so it's still pretty new!

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing. Not exactly a gallery but good enough for inspiration: http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.it/search/label/Styled%20Maps

Comment: If you're looking for the json you can look at the source code. For example lines 57 - 182 in this file http://50problems50days.com/script/50problems.js are the json for this map http://50problems50days.com/. Just search for "stylers" in the chrome console.

Comment: yea ive been doign that. I guess no-one owns the styles, so theres no legalities with me pinching other peoples styles.  Shame the editor doesnt allow u to import JSON to manipulate further.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mapstylr.com/, a map editor easier to use than Google Map Wizard, (with save option), and it has a SHOWCASE of maps with JSONs.

I know this is an old topic, but someone could get here via google as I was.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post with many examples of map created by users with the Style Wizard

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/10/five-great-styled-maps-examples.html

Create your own by using the **The Google Maps Styled Maps Wizard**

```
Navigate to the map region you wish to use to preview your style. Jump to a particular location using the Enter a location field in the top right.
Select a type of feature to style in the Selectors panel.
If you only wish to style the Geometry or Labels for the selected feature type, select the required Element Type.
Select the combination of Stylers to apply to the selected feature type.
Once you are happy with the styling of the feature type, click the Add button in the Map Style panel to save the style and create a new style to work on.
Repeat Steps 2 to 5 to build up the set of styles for your map. Styles are applied in the order they are listed in the Map Style panel.
Select an existing style in the Map Style panel to edit it.
Delete a style by clicking on the trashcan icon to the right of the style number.
When you are happy with your Styled Map, click the Show JSON button to display the JSON object to pass to the style property of your MapOptions object in order to apply the style to a Maps API v3 Map.
To generate an example map with this style using the Static Maps API, click the Static Map button.
```

**Google Maps v3 Style Wizard Tool:**

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: thanks mapperz, but as stated in my Q, i am aware of this tool.  The blog post has nice examples, but I want to see answers that include the json behind examples.